# Spark: replace all smaller values than X by their sum

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe, that has a type and a sub type (broadly speaking).
Say something like:

[image]

What I'd like to do, is for each type, sum all values that are smaller than X (say 100 here), and replace them with one row where sub-type would be "other"
I.e.

[image]

Using window over(Type), I guess I could do two dfs (<100, >=100), where the first I'd sum, pick one row and hack it to get the "Other" single row, and union the result with the >= one. But it seems a rather clumsy way to do it?

(apologies, I don't have access to pyspark right now to do some code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would propose takes into account the need to have a key to apply an aggregation valid for each row, or you would 'loose' the one with value >= 100.
Therefore, the idée is to add a column that identify rows to be aggregated, and provide the other ones with a unique key. After wards, you'll have to clean the result according to the expected result.

Here is what I propose:

```py
    df = df \
        .withColumn("to_agg",
            F.when(F.col("Value") < 100, "Other")
            .otherwise(F.concat(F.col("Type"), F.lit("-"), F.col("Sub-Type")))
        ) \
        .withColumn("sum_other",
            F.sum(F.col("Value")).over(Window.partitionBy("Type", "to_agg"))) \
        .withColumn("Sub-Type",
            F.when(F.col("to_agg") == "Other", F.col("to_agg"))
            .otherwise(F.col("Column_4"))) \
        .withColumn("Value", F.col("sum_other")) \
        .drop("to_agg", "sum_other") \
        .dropDuplicates(("Type", "Sub-Type")) \
        .orderBy(F.col("Type").asc(), F.col("Value").desc())
```

*Note:* the solution to use a `groupBy` is also valid and is simpler but you will have only the columns used in the statement and the result. That's the reason why I prefer using a window function and enable to keep all other columns from the original dataset.

Comment: thanks, makes sense. Yes, I'd prefer window, as I have other columns to keep in the final result.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply replace `Sub-Type` by other for all rows with Value < 100 and then `groupby` and `sum`:

```py
(
    df
    .withColumn('Sub-Type', F.when(F.col('Value') < 100, 'Other').otherwise(F.col('Sub-Type')
    .groupby('Type', 'Sub-Type')
    .agg(
        F.sum('Value').alias('Value')
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, elegant solution, but as I write below, I have other columns to keep, so window is better for me. I didn't mention I have other columns though, so your solution's very valid to what I asked for :)